# How can I clear form except some input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, bootstrap-modal

I try like this :

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    ...
    modal.find('.modal-content form#form-one').not('#datepicker, #timepicker').clearForm();
});
```

I had use `not` on input text who has id datepicker and id timepicker

But, if the script executed, both input text is cleared

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This link may be helpful, http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/clearing-form-data

Answer (score 0):

You may apply particular css class let's say `dontClear` on input fields you wish to keep.

You can then exclude inputs with `dontClear` class as follows :

```
modal.find('.modal-content form#form-one').not('input[class=dontClear]').clearForm();
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Selector in find returns form, not inputs.

```
modal.find('.modal-content form#form-one input').not('#datepicker, #timepicker').clearForm();
```